# Calculating scaling constants for two curves using lmfit minimize or scipy optimize

Tags: python, data-fitting, minimization, lmfit, deconvolution

I have a relatively complex plot which I would like to model. The model consists of two 'phases'/components which have been measured experimentally, however the ratio of these components is unknown. The data is shown in the image: where some combination of the orange and green curves make up the blue curve.

[Complex curve and two components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDxKJ.png)

The model is defined as:

```
    Model = A * (z1 * 0.3 * y1 + z2 * 0.7 * y2) + D
```

where A is an overall scaling, z1 and z2 are the individual scalings for y1 and y2 which are the components. D is an offset.

I have tried to use the lmfit minimise function by defining the fit parameters and residual like so:

```
import lmfit
from lmfit import Minimizer, Parameters, report_fit

fit_params = Parameters()
fit_params.add('A', value=1.00, min=0, max=1)
fit_params.add('z1', value=1, min=0, max=1)
fit_params.add('z2', value=1, min=0, max=1)
fit_params.add('D', value=0.00, min=-5, max=5)

def residual(pars, x, data = total_scatter_expt):
   Data = total_scatter_expt
   Model = A * (z1 * 0.3 * y1 + z2 * 0.7 * y2) + D
   return model - data
```

Because y1 and y2 are also functions it's no entirely clear to me what my x is in the residual or in the minimisation line. For this I have used the x values on the graph in the picture.

```
out = minimize(residual, fit_params, args=(x,))     
print(fit_report(out))
```

This has led to the error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I'm not sure whether this problem would be best described as a deconvolution or perhaps fitting functions of functions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do I get it right...`z1` and `z2` are scaling functions? so you need to get values over the full data range? In that case you do not need `A` and still your system is completely under-determined. If you can assume a certain smoothness you could try with a nth order polynomial or spline.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. z1 and z2 are scaling functions.

Answer (score 1):

You claim that your objective function is:

```
def residual(pars, x, data = total_scatter_expt):
   Data = total_scatter_expt
   Model = A * (z1 * 0.3 * y1 + z2 * 0.7 * y2) + D
   return model - data
```

There a number of problems here:

1. 'data = total_scatter_expt' means the default value for `data` will be the value of `total_scatter_expt` at the time of function *definition* (like when the text of this code is processed). Don't do that.  Anyway, `total_scatter_expt` is not defined.  This cannot be the code you actually ran.
2. You then set `Data` to `total_scatter_expt`.  Again, this cannot be valid code.
3. You capitalize both `Data` and `Model` but then return `model-data`.  Python is case sensitive so your code cannot be valid.
4. You access `A`, `z1`, `y1`, `z2`, `y2`, and `D` which are not defined and never use `pars` or `x`.  Again, your code cannot be valid.

Almost certainly you want to extract the values for the parameters `A`, `D`, etc from `pars`, but you don't do this.  Perhaps try

```
   pvals = pars.valuesdict()
   model = pvals['A'] * (pvals['z1'] ....
```

Probably you mean `x` to encompass `y1` and/or `y2`.

In the future, give the code that actually shows the problem you are actually having.  Do not lie about the error message you get: show the actual messages you get with the actual code you post.

Comment: true...but: while one could argue that there is no proper question...this is not an answer.

Comment: um, wait, "one could argue" that there is no proper question in every situation.  Not only is this not an answer, "one could argue" that there is no answer without a question, and there is no question at all.  There is no spoon. And this is not a comment. ;)

Comment: I did not say this. I am not here. :)